# stunnel entry in /etc/shadow file

Tags: stunnel

I have an unknown entry in my /etc/shadow file

stunnel4:!:11111:0:99999:7:::

(11111) are  numbers that I removed.

Can somebody explain me what application will add this entry under ubuntu 14.04? This entry is not added if I install ubuntu on a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the `stunnel` or [`stunnel4`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/stunnel4) package, or a package that depends on it, this user is created. It's used for "privilegue separation", that means, the `stunnel` service uses it to run tasks that do not need superuser privilegues.

`stunnel` is a program to handle the client or server side of an SSL/TLS connection as "add-on" for existing programs, or as a quick and easy way to do SSL/TLS.